# Can we use MDC for non logging purpose in JAVA

Tags: java, mdc

```
 We have set User Item value in MDC class on Servlet, and getting item value in one common class.

  Using this logic, since we can't pass item value to common class due to some difficulties.

  Can anyone please suggest can we use MDC Log4J for non logging purpose or please suggest a way to achieve our requirement.
```

MDC.put('item', 'xxxx')
   MDC.get('item')

Thanks
Shiv

Answer (score 0):

You can use ThreadLocal variables.

Comment: Thanks Samarth , will it safe use ThreadLocal since it will create memory related issue

Comment: Have tried ThreadLocal and sometimes getting null value  but MDC gives actual value always